# Exclude words that appears in a list from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have such list:

```
stopwords = ['a', 'and', 'is']
```

and such sentence:

```
sentence = 'A Mule is Eating and drinking.'
```

Expected output:

```
reduced = ['mule', 'eating', 'drinking']
```

I have so far:

```
reduced = filter(None, re.match(r'\W+', sentence.lower()))
```

Now how would you filter out the stopwords (Note the upper to lowercase conversion as well as ommitance of punctuation)?

Comment: Do you really want "Foo's" to become "foo" and "s"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter expression is wrong. Change it to:

```
>>> reduced = filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, re.split(r'\W+', sentence.lower()))
```

First argument is the filtering criteria. Also note that to split the sentence you need `re.split` and not `re.match`.

```
>>> list(reduced)
['mule', 'eating', 'drinking']
```

Comment: I like this the most so far. What about empty strings?

Comment: I tried to be as close to your original approach as possible. If you don't want the empty string in the result just add it to stopwords ;-)

Comment: Yes that is why I am giving you the answer, because you implemented the filter as requested as the only person. Added `and w != ''` to the lambda function filtered out empty strings. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to filter the stop words, one way of doing that is by splitting your string and rebuild it without the strings from the list:

```
lst = sentence.split()
' '.join([w for w in lst if w not in stopwords])
```

Regex is useful when you have a pattern that repeats itself, not when you want to match exact occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with not going with the regex route, you can just use list comprehension , `string.split()` and check if the string is not in `stopwords` .

Example -

```
>>> stopwords = ['a', 'and', 'is']
>>> sentence = 'a mule is eating and drinking'
>>> reduced = [s.lower() for s in sentence.split() if s.lower() not in stopwords]
>>> reduced
['mule', 'eating', 'drinking']
```

As, a performance benefit, you can also convert the stopwords list to `set` using the `set()` function, and then do the lookup in it, as search in `set` is O(1) .

Comment: did edit my question, upper and lowercase conversion is in play as well. Stopword list is lowercase and acutal sentence is/ can be uppercasy.

Comment: Edited answer, you can just use `s.lower()`

Comment: As a performance enhancement, you could also create a set from the stopwords `stopset = set(stopwords)` before running the comprehension, and then membership lookups would be O(1) instead of O(n), as with the list.

Comment: @SirBenBenji What do you want to do to punctuation?

Answer (score 1):

If one is working with textual material it is worthwhile to make the observation that the NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit) is a "framework" for analyzing text. Not only does it have many of the built in functions one would like when working with text, the NLTK Book is a tutorial for both learning Python and text analysis at the same time. How cool is that!

For example,

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords.words('english')
```

gives us a list of 127 stop words in the English language. The first few in that list are: i, me, my, myself, and we. Notice that these words are in lower case.

So the problem stated above, as processed one particular way by NLTK, would look like:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

raw = 'All human rules are more or less idiotic, I suppose. 
It is best so, no doubt. The way it is now, the asylums can 
hold the sane people, but if we tried to shut up the insane 
we should run out of building materials. -- Mark Twain'

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
words  = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)

sw = stopwords.words('english')

reduce = [w.lower() for w in words if w.lower() not in sw]
```

The line:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
```

is a regex expression used by the tokenizer to strip punctuation. Much of the time it is stems of words that are important. For example, "human" is the stem of "human's," and analysis centers around the noun "human" and not its various forms. If we need to keep such detail the regex can be refined. No doubt there is time to be invested in building robust regex expressions, but practice makes perfect.

If you don't mind the overhead of learning NLTK, for example, because you are doing routine text analysis, then this might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the punctuation:

```
from string import punctuation
stopwords = set(['a', 'and', 'is'])

sentence = 'A Mule is Eating and drinking.'

print([word.strip(punctuation) for word in sentence.lower().split() if word not in stopwords])
['mule', 'eating', 'drinking']
```

Using a regex is the wrong approach as you are going to end up splitting single words like `"Foo's"` in `"foo"` and `"s"`, if you are going to use a regex don't re.split use findall and filter instead of having to filter out empty strings for no reason:

```
stopwords = set(['a', 'and', 'is'])

reduced = filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, re.findall(r"\w+", sentence.lower()))
print(reduced)
['mule', 'eating', 'drinking']
```

To keep "Mules's" as a single word with a regex:

```
sentence = 'A Mule"s  Eating and drinking.'
reduced = filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, re.findall(r"\w+\S\w+|\w+", sentence.lower()))
print(reduced)
'mule"s', 'eating', 'drinking']
```

Your own regex and the accepted answer will split the word into two parts which I doubt is what you actually want:

```
In [7]: sentence = 'A Mule"s Eating and drinking.'
In [8]: reduced = filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, re.split(r'\W+', sentence.lower()))
In [9]: reduced
Out[9]: ['mule', 's', 'eating', 'drinking', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code you will delete the stopwords. It works in PySpark

```
stopwordsT=["a","about","above","above","across","after","afterwards","again","against","all","almost","alone","along","already","also","although","always","am","among", "amongst", "amoungst","amount", "an","and","another","any","anyhow","anyone","anything","anyway","anywhere","are","around","as","at","back","be","became","because","become","becomes","becoming","been","before","beforehand","behind","being","below","beside","besides","between","beyond","bill","both","bottom","but","by","call","can","cannot","cant","co","con","could","couldnt","cry","de","describe","detail","do","done","down","due","during","each","eg","eight","either","eleven","else", "elsewhere", "empty", "enough", "etc", "even", "ever", "every", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "except", "few", "fifteen", "fify", "fill", "find", "fire", "first", "five", "for", "former", "formerly", "forty", "found", "four", "from", "front", "full", "further", "get", "give", "go", "had", "has", "hasnt", "have", "he", "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein", "hereupon", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "however", "hundred", "ie", "if", "in", "inc", "indeed", "interest", "into", "is", "it", "its", "itself", "keep", "last", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "ltd", "made", "many", "may", "me", "meanwhile", "might", "mill", "mine", "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "move", "much", "must", "my", "myself", "name", "namely", "neither", "never", "nevertheless", "next", "nine", "no", "nobody", "none", "noone", "nor", "not", "nothing", "now", "nowhere", "of", "off", "often", "on", "once", "one", "only", "onto", "or", "other", "others", "otherwise", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own","part", "per", "perhaps", "please", "put", "rather", "re", "same", "see", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", "serious", "several", "she", "should", "show", "side", "since", "sincere", "six", "sixty", "so", "some", "somehow", "someone", "something", "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhere", "still", "such", "system", "take", "ten", "than", "that", "the", "their", "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby", "therefore", "therein", "thereupon", "these", "they", "thickv", "thin", "third", "this", "those", "though", "three", "through", "throughout", "thru", "thus", "to", "together", "too", "top", "toward", "towards", "twelve", "twenty", "two", "un", "under", "until", "up", "upon", "us", "very", "via", "was", "we", "well", "were", "what", "whatever", "when", "whence", "whenever", "where", "whereafter", "whereas", "whereby", "wherein", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether", "which", "while", "whither", "who", "whoever", "whole", "whom", "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without", "would", "yet", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves", "the"]
sentence = "about esto alone es a una already pruba across para after ver too si top funciona"
lst = sentence.split()
' '.join([w for w in lst if w not in stopwordsT])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
stopwords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
sentence = "Word1 Word5 word2 Word4 wORD3"

reduced = sentence.split()

for i in reduced:
    if i.lower() in stopwords:
        reduced.remove(i)
```

Comment: `list.remove` has `O(n)` complexity, don't use it.